# Reminders on the watch is showing two reminders lists

Tags: watchos, apple-watch

I have Apple Watch 3 GPS running watchOS 4.1.

Reminders app on the watch is showing two reminders lists. One is empty and one contains items which I really have across all my Apple devices.

Any ideas? Is it normal?

[image: reminders app]